# Symmetric $S$ in $S^{-1}AS = A^T$

Tags: symmetric-matrices, transpose

A rather tough homework problem of mine:

Let $K$ be a field and $A \in K^{n \times n}$. Prove that there exists a symmetric matrix $S \in GL_n(K)$ with $S^{-1}AS = A^T$.

What's the best proof you can come up with?

I've had several ideas, most of them leading to dead ends or fake proofs. Evidently, it suffices to find a symmetric $S$, such that $AS$ ist symmetric. One idea would be to consider a symmetric $S$ and explicitely computer the terms of $AS$. To force it to be symmetric, we'll end up with a homogeneous system of linear equations - so in each equation we can fix one of the variables in $S$ in terms of the others. By some counting, we'll end up with $n$ variables that are not fixed. These can be used to force $S$ to be invertible.

The problem with this argument is that you ought to be extremely careful - and most problematic: it gets messy with too many $0$'s in $A$. The argument would (probably) work without $0$'s but meh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed a paper by Taussky and Zassenhaus: [Symmetric Similarity Transform](https://msp.org/pjm/1959/9-3/pjm-v9-n3-p25-p.pdf).

I spend some time understanding this paper, and wrote a note how I understood it in my words. To understand the paper fully, it requires some knowledge on Module theory such as 'Structure Theorem for Finitely Generated Modules over PID'. The following is a starting point:

**Case 1: Minimal Polynomial Coincides with Characteristic Polynomial**

> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix over a field $K$. Suppose also that the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial of $A$ coincide. Then any invertible matrix $X$ satisfying $XA=A^TX$ is symmetric.

Proof)

Consider the following system ($\Sigma_A$) of matrix equations.
$$(1) \ \ XA=A^TX, \ \  (2) \ \ X=X^T.$$

Note that the below system is equivalent to ($\Sigma_A$).
$$(1') \ \ XA=A^TX^T,\ \ (2) \ \ X=X^T.$$
The linear transform $X\mapsto (XA-A^TX^T, \ \ X-X^T)$ has rank at most $n^2-n$ since both components are skew-symmetric.

Thus, the solution space of the system ($\Sigma_A$) has dimension at least $n$.

Now, fix a non-singular transform $X_0$ such that $X_0A=A^TX_0$. Then
$$XA=A^TX \textrm{  if and only if  } X_0^{-1}XA=AX_0^{-1}X.$$
This yields an isomorphism $X\mapsto X_0^{-1}X$ between $\{X\mid XA=A^TX\}$ and $C_A=\{X'\mid X'A=AX'\}=\{f(A)|f\in K[t]\}$. Since $\textrm{dim}_{K}C_A = n$, the solution space for (1) has dimension $n$. Then the solution space for ($\Sigma_A$) has dimension at most $n$ because it involves more equations. Therefore, the dimension must be exactly $n$.
Hence, every matrix $X$ satisfying (1) must also satisfy (2).

The following is not discussed in detail in the paper, so I will include it.

**Case 2: General Case**

> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix over a field $K$. Then there exists an invertible symmetric matrix $X$ such that $XA=A^T X$.

Proof)

Let $X_0$ be an invertible matrix over $K$ such that $A=X_0^{-1} J X_0$ with $J$ is consisted of blocks on diagonal, each block is a companion matrix of $p^s$ for some irreducible polynomial $p$ and $s\geq 1$. Say, $J=\textrm{diag}\{C_1,\ldots, C_r\}$.  Now, we may have distinct blocks in $J$ corresponding to the same irreducible polynomial. Consider
$$
XA=A^T X \Longleftrightarrow X_0^{-T}XX_0^{-1}J=J^T X_0^{-T}XX_0^{-1},
$$
where I used the notation $X_0^{-T} = (X_0^{-1})^T$.

By Case 1, we can find a symmetric invertible matrix corresponding to each companion matrix in $J$. Put $ X_0^{-T}XX_0^{-1}=\textrm{diag}\{Y_1,\ldots ,Y_r\}$ such that $Y_i C_i = C_i^T Y_i$ and $Y_i$ is symmetric invertible and of the same size with $C_i$ for each $1\leq i\leq r$.

Then we can put a symmetric invertible matrix 
$$
X=X_0^T \textrm{diag}\{Y_1,\ldots ,Y_r\} X_0, 
$$
which satisfies $XA=A^T X$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's kind of peculiar though, how this was proposed as a homework problem for a 2nd Semester Linear Algebra course. Valuable nonetheless!

Comment: Maybe this one is easier and explicit for Case 1: https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0024379599002104/1-s2.0-S0024379599002104-main.pdf?_tid=84d2e5b9-9036-4f5e-86a6-0584288f5018&acdnat=1527195322_defaf88cd60b267885fb7c70ad6c18f1 since we only need existence

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about it, I guess it's okay - I didn't mention there were also two parts of the problem leading to this one, one proving that these matrices transforming companion matrices is always symmetric (which is just computation) and that a matrix is always similar to its Frobenius Normal Form. (And we've already shown that $A$ is similar to $A^T$.)